# aufs Root File System On Usb Flash

Tags: networking, dhcp, interface, read-only, unionfs

I configured aufs as a Root File System On Usb Flash Drive by this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash). So the first brunch is real root FS and it is read-only. The second brunch FS is in memory and it is read-write capable. Both brunches combined in one file-based Copy-On-Write union and mounted at **/** .

All things seams working well, but network interface.
While the Ubuntu 11.10 Oneric 3.0.0-16-server x86_64 booting I see next message:
**Waiting network configuration**

After it boots eth0 don't bring UP:

```
rootubuntu:~# ifconfig
lo Link encap:Local Loopback
met addr:127.O.O.1 Mask:255.O.O.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACI< RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:O dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:O overruns:O carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:0 (0.0 6) TX bytes:0 (0.0 6)
```

restarting networking not helping:

```
root@ubuntu:~# /etc/init.d/networking restart
* Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enabie again some interfaces
* Reconfiguring network interfaces...
dhclient3: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to bring up ethO.
```

The library **libc.so.6** remains the same place at **/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so** and link **/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6** for it.
When I boot normally (without aufs as root FS ) all things go well again.

How to FIX it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash#Apparmor) is short: this is the problem with [apparmor compatibility](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1220145).

```
 apt-get install apparmor-utils
 aa-complain dhclient3
```

Seems like apparmor do not like how aufs working. In this case other problems can happen due to usage of aufs with apparmor.

There is [another way](http://www.languid.org/blog/index.php/2009-10/an-ubuntu-appliance/#more-55) to fix problem.

Or you will need to remove **apparmor**.

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop
update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
aptitude remove apparmor apparmor-utils
```